# Text Flows Out of <p> Element With Overflow Hidden And Won't Center

Tags: html, css

[image: Here's a picture of my current menu]

I am trying to make menu items out of the following items, but I'm struggling with making the text inside the paragraph element responsive to its parent. I tried all positioning combinations, as well as every possible combination with percentages and sizing, but nothing worked the way it's supposed to.

I just want to have the text centered inside the circles...

```css
.div-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="navbar-text">
            <div class="div-1">
               <p>Home</p>
            </div>
            <div class="div-1">
              <p>Services</p>
            </div>
            <div class="div-1">
              <p>Programs</p>
            </div>
        </span>
```

Comment: The text isn't actually overflowing the `<p>` because it still has a larger rectangular box that the text is contained within (use `outline:` to see it, not `border`).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I wasn't actually aware until now of the difference between outline and border... Mostly I've been using border for just about anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see I used [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to achieve what you wanted.

```css
.navbar-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.div-1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="navbar-text">
  <div class="div-1">
     <p>Home</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-1">
    <p>Services</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-1">
    <p>Programs</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: I tried flex too, it won't work with flex. There is still the overflow and nothing is changing, I even put !important in case the Bootstrap was overruling it. I honestly don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: You can see that the code above is valid, if it does not work in your case then you will need to look closely in your browser console to see what exactly is overwriting it. It could be some styling on the general `div` or `p` tags. It is hard to give you a better answer, not knowing the structure of your code within the application.

Comment: Absolutely, I did some experimenting and made it work :) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go using flex box for aligment.

```css
.div-1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items:center;
     justify-content: center;
}

.div-1 p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span class="navbar-text" style="display:flex">
    <div class="div-1">
       <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-1">
      <p>Services</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-1">
      <p>Programsasdfsdfsdfsdfds</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Flexbox won't work, I already tried it, even with !important. It's not changing anything, the overflow is still visible outside the p element and outside the circles even, just like in the pic

Answer (score 0):

```
.div-1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items:center;
     justify-content: center;
}

.div-1 p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add not-flex approach
You can try to use text-align and line-height. But one issue here - it doesn't support multiline. If you want long texts - then use flex.

```css
.div-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.div-1 > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="navbar-text">
    <div class="div-1">
        <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-1">
        <p>Services</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-1">
        <p>Programs</p>
    </div>
</span>
```